# Object declaration vs instantiation

Tags: java

Is there a difference in time execution and memory between

```
Test t = new Test();
t.testSomething();
```

and

```
new Test().testSomething();
```

I do find the difference in stability when creating Android apps, but then again I need an explanation as to why.

Comment: Only different if you go on to use `t` for something else.

Comment: `I do find the difference in stability when creating android apps` - what do you mean by that? Can you elaborate what difference in stability you found?

Comment: The code above is identical when compiled, so there's no difference. Especially in anything related to performance.

Comment: @Kayaman What about scope? Will Java be able to garbage-collect the second example earlier than the first, thinking about a laaaaarge method where the scope for `t` is looong.

Comment: @Zabuza even if the scope is large, if the variable isn't used anymore it won't make a difference in the execution. Scope affects the compiler, not so much the running code. Even in the second version it would most likely be freed after the method ends as the stack is popped. Not to mention that the whole object could be instantiated on the stack in special cases. Trying to understand the JVM execution based on 2 lines of code is like shooting in the dark.

Comment: @Eran my old company had a lot of thing like AccountCase acct = new AccountCase() and assigning Account t = acct.getAllAccount() which gives out like > 50000k lines of data, and they kept similar object like that in different variables, and they would loop or select whatever from that 50000k lines and creates a very slow processing. I just bypassed all those variables and directly used for examples like for (Account acct : new AccountCase().getAllAccount()), and did that for all other similar instances of different objects. If that makes sense. The question above is the simplest i can deduce.

Answer (score 2):

If `t` is a local variable and you do nothing else with `t` then the two are completely identical.

If `t` is a *field* that may be accessed by others, then the two can differ quite significantly, especially in multi-threaded code.